# Bash eval and dynamic call the variable

Tags: bash, case, eval

I have a bash script which use 'eval' command. 
I don't know if it's a good idea, but I need to do this :

```
i=1
for e in $items; do 
    echo $i - $e
    eval vm_$i=$e
    let i++
done
```

Then I display a menu like this :

```
while [ "$c" != "q" ]; do
    read c
    case $c in
            1)
            echo "CB Node $vm_1"
            ssh "$vm_1" "couchbase-cli server-info -c $cluster"
            ;;
            2)
            ;;
            3)
            ;;
            l) echo "Listing cluster nodes... "

            ;;
            q) exit 2
    esac
```

done

It works, but now I want to use variable $c in my 'case' to generate the good variable $vm1  ($vm_$c,  $c corresponding to $i in fact..). 
I tried some things like :  echo "CB Node $( eval $vm$c)", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you use arrays instead? `node[i]=$e; echo ${node[i]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would all be a lot more elegant as well as secure if you used an array instead.

```
vm=(dummy $items)
vm[0]=''  # get rid of dummy zero index

while true; do
     read -p 'Quick, do something! ' c
     case $c in
       [1-${#vm[@]}])
         echo "CB Node ${vm[$c]}"
         ssh "${vm[$c]}" "couchbase-cli server-info -c $cluster" ;;
       l)
         : ;;
       q) exit 2;;
       *) echo 'Try again.';;
    esac
done
```

The array and indirect reference `${!var}` are Bash-only constructs.

Comment: Thank you.   What does exactly 'set -- $items'  ?   I don't understand the indirect references...

Comment: The `set` copies the items to `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc for easy reference. Depending on what's in `$items` you could perhaps use `read -a` instead to read the items directly into the array without a loop; but then that produces a zero-based array.

Comment: Actually, updated the answer to use a direct assignment instead of going via `set`.

Comment: I can't use a manual direct array assignment, because I don't know how many nodes there is (I did'nt say, $items is a list of database cluster nodes).

Comment: If you have them in `$items` then you can.  If you don't, how did the original code manage to work?